# How tun set animation on each element one after one and not in all together

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with my method.
I have 5 input fields on screen, and when this screen is created (onCreate method), i want that this element will appear with animation one after one and not all together.
Here is the method that I created.

```
private void setInputsAnimation() {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
            final int finalI = i;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    inputs.get(finalI).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    YoYo.with(Techniques.DropOut)
                            .duration(1000)
                            .repeat(0)
                            .playOn(inputs.get(finalI));
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I run this method , the animation is working but for element together, and not one after one.

Here is the inputs array method:

```
private List<EditText> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

private List<EditText> inputs() {
        inputs.add(et1);
        inputs.add(et2);
        inputs.add(et3);
        inputs.add(et4);
        inputs.add(et5);
        return inputs;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to use delay like this : delay(finalI*250)

Comment: Hi @KasımÖzdemir, It's working, but why ? hhh

Comment: Otherwise they play together